# Example of two identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability

Omega=[0,1] with P=dx. Give an example of two identically distributed random variables X,Y on (omega, P) with P(X not equal to Y)=1.

Thank you, and please forgive me formatting. I am not yet used to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X(\omega) = \omega$, $Y(\omega) = 1-\omega$.

Clearly $X(\omega) = Y(\omega)$ iff $\omega = \frac{1}{2}$, hence $P\{ \omega | X(\omega) \neq Y(\omega) \} = 1$.

$F_X(\alpha) = P \{ \omega | X(\omega) \le \alpha \} = \alpha$, 
$F_Y(\alpha) = P \{ \omega | Y(\omega) \le \alpha \} = \alpha$, hence $X,Y$ are identically distributed.